# GWT XML Replace class

Tags: xml, gwt, gxt

```
<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

<replace-with class="hu.goodimpress.szamlazo.ajax.client.utils.JSON.JsonReader">
<when-type-is class="com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.JsonReader"/>
<when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
</replace-with>
<replace-with class="hu.goodimpress.szamlazo.ajax.client.utils.JSON.JsonReader">
<when-type-is class="com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.JsonReader"/>
<when-property-is name="user.agent" value="opera"/>
</replace-with>
<replace-with class="hu.goodimpress.szamlazo.ajax.client.utils.JSON.JsonReader">
<when-type-is class="com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.JsonReader"/>
<when-property-is name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
</replace-with>


<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT"/>
<inherits name="hu.goodimpress.szamlazo.ajax.Start"/>


<entry-point class="hu.goodimpress.szamlazo.client.Szamlazo"/>
</module>
```

but gwt not changed GXT JsonReader, my JsonReader :((
i use debug mode.... 
so it would be easier to replace the central classes derive from the time and place as if the code is to be less

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GXT `JsonReader` but there are a couple of hints:

Replace rules can be overridden by other modules, so may be there is some other module, which overrides your rule

Replace rules affects only objects created using GWT.create. E.g. rules only work for:

`JsonReader reader = GWT.create(JsonReader.class);`

And never for:

`JsonReader reader = new JsonReader();`

Comment: Unfortunatly, JsonReader takes a constructor argument, so GWT.create isn't going to work to create it. Also worth pointing out that if you always want something replaced, there is no need to check the properties - and if any of those properties cause the same replacement, all of the <when-property-is> tags can be put in the same <replace-with> tag.